# How to color even/odd table rows in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

OK I have a question I have this code which I will list below. I need to make the even rows a light blue and the odd a white. Now it doesnt show up so I am assume I am doing soemthing wrong. Now do I need to do the  order in it so that way the rows will look the way I need it to do?

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Html Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table width=\"50%\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">";
$rowcount=0;
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
echo " <td align=\"center\" style=\"width:100px\">".$x."</td>\n";
if ($x%4==0) {
  if ($rowcount%2==0){
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#5CCDC9\">\n";
   }
   else{
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">\n";
    }
    $rowscount++;
   }
 }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

ok I am trying to understand this better after reading a few things this is my new code

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Html Tables</title>
<style type=<\"text/css\">
.even { bgcolor:#5CCDC9; }
.odd { bgcolor:#FFFFFF; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table width=\"50%\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">";
$rowcount=0;
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
echo " <td align=\"center\" style=\"width:100px\">".$x."</td>\n";
if ($x%4==0) {
 if ($rowcount%2==0){
    echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr class=\"even\">\n";
   }
   else{
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr class=\"odd\">\n";
    }
    $rowcount++;
   }
 }
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

now i just dont understand how to write it in PHP I am reading and trying to figure out how to make sense of it. Sorry I am a newbie at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `$rowcount` in your conditional and initialization but you are using `$rowscount` (with in "s") in your incrementing.

Note: you should really be using CSS for that rather than the `bgcolor` property.

Comment: @AJ Thank you. You are as well.

Comment: well i have to use  modular operator to use background color

Comment: @andy Re: my note. I'm not suggesting don't style the rows using modulus on the server side. I'm suggesting instead of using bgcolor="..." use style="alt-row" or something similar to that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but dont understand? Does that make sense

Answer (score 3):

you have a typo...change `$rowscount++` to `$rowcount++`

Comment: I love how timestamps are **so** visible.  First answer doesn't seem to matter...what's the motivation to answer quickly?

Comment: But... at the same time, if an answer takes longer to write, it won't be the accepted answer because others get their first (even when the answer which took longer is more flushed out).

Comment: I think upvoted and accepted are indirectly related.  Only one person can decide which answer to accept.

Comment: I'd say that they're dependent variables, though it is not always linearly dependent.

Comment: Hey @AJ... I up-voted you so you get some additional reputation. You were 6 seconds faster than me (your timestamp said "6 seconds ago" when the page refreshed to show my post). Either way, I'm here to help people not get reputation points, you're answer was not there when I started typing mine. Period, I'm not starting a debate here. We both independently debugged the issue and had helpful... but identical :)... answers.

Comment: I have to use modulus operators to set the background color

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with CSS.  You can use the `nth-child` rule to select odd and even rows of the table and colour them differently. That way you don't need the modulus operator `if` statement you're using.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mX5Up/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's a little bit cleaner and it works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Html Tables</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<?php
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    if ($x % 2 == 0) {
        echo '            <tr bgcolor="#5CCDC9">', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">', PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '                <td align="center" style="width:100px">' . $x . '</td>', PHP_EOL;
    echo '            </tr>', PHP_EOL;
}
?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```